# PyQt: Getting the index of an appended row after QStandardItemModel.appendRow()

Tags: pyqt, qstandarditemmodel

I am [appending a row](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QStandardItemModel.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QStandardItemModel.appendRow) in PyQt like so:

```
model = QStandardItemModel(0, 3)
model.appendRow([item1, item2, item2])
```

Now I would like to get the [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QModelIndex.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex) of the appended row so that I can select the row in the user interface using [QItemSelectionModel.select()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QItemSelectionModel.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.select). How can this be done?

Comment: [`item.row()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#row), after the insertion. Also, see [`item.index()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#index) and [`model.indexFromItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#indexFromItem).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the universal answer, but in my specific case this was enough:

```
model = QStandardItemModel(0, 3)
model.appendRow([item1, item2, item2])
last_row = model.rowCount() - 1
self.myTableView.selectRow(last_row)
```